# GUI components, graphs and charts . 

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graph

Okay, so I am stumped. Does anyone know of a simple method for Java using NetBeans that will draw a graph (preferably a Pie Chart) using a paint component on the jPanel?

I have Googled, and researched and can't find a straight answer. I am still learning and this is the last component of my final for this class. I only need the method, if anyone knows a simple way to do this. It doesn't need to change as the requirement states that I only need a graphic; the program logic parses from the temp.textField. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

P.S. Yes, I have tried JFreeCharts.

```
private void jPanel1ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {

    // Bar graph component and logic. 

    BorderLayout panelMapLayout = new BorderLayout();

    jPanel1.setLayout(panelMapLayout);
    jPanel1.add(Graph, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JFrame fr = new JFrame();
   final int width = 300;
   final int height = 400;
   fr.setSize(width, height);
   fr.setTitle("Grade Bar Graph");
   fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   fr.setVisible(true);
   String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the String file name?");
    barGraphComponent component = new barGraphComponent();

    fr.setVisible(true);


}
```

Above is my code - only a portion, but I think this will work. Anyone have any ideas how I can add logic to it? If need be I will throw the whole code up. I do not need it to change, only display an initial set of integers; but how do I get those integers into my graph?

Comment: Why doesn't JFreeChart suit your needs?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, it probably would. But I am having trouble integrating the methods and I am in a time crunch now. It is tough being a full-time student, learning a new language, working 50 - 60 hours a week, and having a family. . .

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0):

Use JCommon & JFreechart jars. 
I hope u can go with it..!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

  public class JavaApplication3 {
        DefaultCategoryDataset categoryDataset;
        private String YaxisXaxis = "Hospital mortality rate";
        private String Xaxis[] = {"2009APR-2010MAR", "2010APR-2011MAR", "2011APR-2011NOV"};
        double val[] = {1.7879989, 1.6252073, 1.5941324};
     JFreeChart chart ;
        public void getinput() {              
        }
        void setinp() {
            categoryDataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                categoryDataset.setValue(val[i], YaxisXaxis, Xaxis[i]);
            }
        }
        void drawcharts(){
             chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("XYZ HOSPITALS", // Title
                          "Year",              // X-Axis label
                          "Number of Students",// Y-Axis label
                          categoryDataset,         // Dataset
                          PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                          true,                     // Show legend
                          true,
                          false
                         );
        }
        void savechart()
        {
                  String fileName="d:/sp.jpg";
            try {
                /**
                 * This utility saves the JFreeChart as a JPEG
                 * First Parameter: FileName
                 * Second Parameter: Chart To Save
                 * Third Parameter: Height Of Picture
                 * Fourth Parameter: Width Of Picture
                 */
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(fileName), chart, 800, 600);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
        }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
           JavaApplication3 obj =new  JavaApplication3();
           obj.setinp();
           obj.drawcharts();
           obj.savechart();

        }
    }
```

Try this sample... U can get easily...